# SQL Server Express max value after

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, subquery

With a table like the following, how can I select the first higher value after a certain id?

```
+-----+--------+-----------+
| id  | weight | timestamp |
+-----+--------+-----------+
|  1  |   700  |  datetime |
|  2  |   600  |  datetime |
|  3  |   800  |  datetime |
|  4  |  1000  |  datetime |
|  5  |   450  |  datetime |
|  6  |   900  |  datetime |
|  7  |   560  |  datetime |
|  8  |   500  |  datetime |
|  9  |   600  |  datetime |
| 10  |   880  |  datetime |
+-----+--------+-----------+
```

For example if I query for the id 1 should return 4, for the id 5 should return 6, while for the id 8 should return 10

Comment: For `id = 1`, I think the answer is "3" not "4" and for 8, it should be "9" and not '10".

Comment: Your question should read: `For example if I query for the id 1 should return 3` (not 4) because 800 > than 700

Comment: @Icarus I'm looking for the first bigger value before his smaller

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
select top 1 t.*
from t
where t.weight > (select t2.weight from t t2 where t2.id = @id)
order by t.id;
```

Hold on.  You are looking for the last in the series of increasing ids after a certain value.  This might be what you really want:

```
select top 1 t.*
from (select t.*, lead(weight) over (order by id) as next_weight
      from t
     ) t
where t.weight > (select t2.weight from t t2 where t2.id = @id) and
      (t.weight > t.next_weight or t.next_weight is null)
order by t.id;
```

Comment: and in this case t2 stands for..? :/

Comment: @Vixed . . . It is a table alias.

Comment: simply amazing @Gordon! Just in case in more simple than I imagine... there is any simple way to get the id before this?

Comment: there is any simple way to get the id before this?

Comment: doesn't checks the timestamp